Pressure Measured inside Inflatables
When at sea level the air pressure is ~1 bar (14.5 psi).
So when I pump up a SUP at the beach I'd expect to start at 1 bar, yet the gauge of the pump starts at 0 and I'm supposed to pump until it reaches 0.8-1.03 bar (12-15 psi).
Is the measurement relative to the outside pressure? Please explain.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure_measurement#Gauge

Well it actually measures a kind of relative pressure, scale starting at 0, called gauge pressure.
The wikipedia says

Gauge pressure is zero-referenced against ambient air pressure, so it is equal to absolute pressure minus atmospheric pressure. A tire pressure gauge is an example of gauge pressure measurement; when it indicates zero, then the pressure it is measuring is the same as the ambient pressure. Most sensors for measuring up to 50 bar are manufactured in this way, since otherwise the atmospheric pressure fluctuation (weather) is reflected as an error in the measurement result.

This is the case with the SUP. So, yh, it's relative to the outside pressure. If you get 1 atm in that, means it's 1 atm above the outside pressure (not always ~2atm)
Hope it helps.
